# Wpf selecteditem not working - Linq

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

i have one grid binded with some data, coming from database as bellow and one edit button

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="SParts_grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="32,101,32,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="187" Width="530" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Part No" Binding="{Binding Path=SPartID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Code" Width="85" Binding="{Binding Path=SPartCode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Name" Width="160" Binding="{Binding Path=SPartName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=ModelName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Path=SPartLocation}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Width="58" Binding="{Binding Path=SPartActive}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,323,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
```

all data fetched from db table called `TblSpareParts` just one column `"ModelName"` is from another table called `TblBikeModels`

so my code is below to fetch data

```
window loaded function

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadParts();
}

private void LoadParts()
{
    RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
    var AllPArts = (from s in conn.TblSpareParts
                    join m in conn.TblBikeModels on s.ModelID equals m.ModelID
                    select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartID, m.ModelName }).ToArray();
    SParts_grid.ItemsSource = AllPArts;
}
```

it works well but now if i need the selecteditem it does not work as below

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                TblSparePart SelectedSPData = SParts_grid.SelectedItem as TblSparePart;
                if (SelectedSPData == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You Must Select a Part");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected");
                }
        }
```

but when i use this `LoadParts` function then `selecteditem` works fine but it does not show the data in `ModelName` column

```
private void LoadParts()
        {
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            List<TblSparePart> AllPArts = (from s in conn.TblSpareParts
                                            select s).ToList();
            SParts_grid.ItemsSource = AllPArts;
        }
```

Basically problem is in `LoadParts` function

Comment: can you tell us what kind of context you are working with? (ADO, Entity Framework..)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartID, m.ModelName }`, you return an anonymous type, instead of `TblSparePart` object.

That's why the casting `SParts_grid.SelectedItem as TblSparePart;` returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks, but how i make the object of that single table where i also need the one column of another table

Comment: can you give me an example how i make object where i am using var AllParts

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, you should avoid of using anonymous types for binding data. Try to bind each row to single model object

Comment: Thanks, can you please give an example of binding each row to single model object

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a UI design problem. Working with joined tables in `DataGrid` will definitely get duplicated data, that's what you may have to avoid. A better solution is to work with two `DataGrid`s or (`ComboBox` and a `DataGrid`) one for the models table the other one is for items related to the model.

If you are working with Entity framework, then the task is much easier. You just have to point the binding to the related model table.

Take a look at this case :

```
public class Item 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Model Model {get;set;}
}

public class Model 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Here you can do the as you did secondly. By loading only Items table in your `DataGrid` you can add a column that points to the Model Name property. It's going to be ready to be shown due to lazy loading that EF offers.

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=Model.name}" />
```